# How to properly set up a Database to take advantage of LINQ/MVC

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, database-design, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been given a task to set up a large database with lookup tables, one to ones, many to manys, one to manys.  and I'm looking for resources on where to begin, as I have never set up a database this large.

Each department will have many functions as well an owner of the department.

Each function will have many processes as well as an owner of the function who will report to the department owner.

Each process will have many procedures as well as an owner of the process who will report to the function owner.  These procedures can be linked to other procedures in other departments so we can have a nice chain linking system.

And all of the above can have KPI's associated with them.

The site will be built on MVC/LINQ/Razor so I need to build the database in a way that we can easily set up Models and LINQ can take full advantage.

So any resources of suggestion to help get me started on the right path will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework or some other ORM would be what I implement the backend with. Especially using LINQ, as LINQ to Entity is very nice IMO. I also have used these technologies to build large scale apps without problems.

EF is really nice as you can build a code-first implementation, by designing your classes and letting EF generate the schema for the DB. If you do not know how to build DB design properly, let EF do it for you.

Comment: any sites or books you would recommend?  I think I will go with EF.

Comment: A little older article, but good start and good source...http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my experience and opinion, using LINQ-to-SQL, you just need to take care of have a relational database with tables well normalized, specially for the many-to-many relationships. Take care of adding primary keys to your tables and indexes, and as far as I know, LINQ will take care of the rest.

One thing I do on complex queries, is to create stored procedures to be used on linq and therefore I can take advantage of the store procedure caching on SQL instead of waiting for a complex query to be generated and executed by LINQ on the fly.